# Как посмотреть погоду с помощью VBS скрипта?

Tags: vbscript, jscript

Стоит задача: разработать VBS script, который позволяет просматривать погоду. При этом в качестве параметров может указываться конкретный город.
В PowerShell и cmd эта проблема решалась с помощью curl wttr.in/город, но для vbs не это не работает, а другой информации я не нашел:(

Answer (score 0):

Почему нельзя использовать тот же метод как и в PowerShell?

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://wttr.in/Moscow?A", False
o.send
' o.responseText содержит ответ
```

Для того чтобы включить ANSI-форматирование независимо от User-Agent'а,
мы используем опцию `?A`